# Excel - Lookup value with a condition

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I've been trying to do the following:

- `Sheet1`, lookup value `A3` in `Data`
- `Data`, check whether the found value has a `1` in column `M`

  - Yes: Paste the value of column `K` from `Data` in column `B3` in `Sheet1`
  - No: Carry on searching through the sheet and display `0` if nothing is found

This is what I have so far, it finds the correct K value, but I need to enter shift+ctrl+enter to get the value ...

```
=INDEX('TLN Data'!$B$1:$Z$15000; MATCH(1;(A3='TLN Data'!$B$1:$B$15000)*(1='TLN Data'!$M$1:$M$15000);0); 10)
```

All help is much appreciated!

--

Sheet1

[image]

TLN Data

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an INDEX function to get a version that doesn't need CSE, i.e.

`=INDEX('TLN Data'!$B$1:$Z$15000; MATCH(1;INDEX((A3='TLN Data'!$B$1:$B$15000)*(1='TLN Data'!$M$1:$M$15000);0);0);10)`

That would be preferable to SUMPRODUCT in some cases, e.g. where the return value is text, or if you have multiple matches and you only want the first.

You can also use LOOKUP like this:

`=LOOKUP(2;1/(A3='TLN Data'!$B$1:$B$15000)/(1='TLN Data'!$M$1:$M$15000);'TLN Data'!$K$1:$K$15000)`

With that version if there are multiple matches that returns the **last**

Comment: Neither formula should need "array entry" - what results did you get?

Comment: Pardon me, some ass in the office set calculations to Manual ... -.-

Comment: Sorry for waking up the dead, but I've seen the `lookup` version in a few places on the web, but never with a full explanation of how that specific syntax works. What are the slashes doing in there? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using `SUMPRODUCT` (which you don't need to enter as an array):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
    --('TLN Data'!$B$1:$B$15000=A3), 
    --('TLN Data'!$M$1:$M$15000=1),
    'TLN Data'!$K1:$K$15000)
```

This uses a similar logic to your `MATCH` formula above:

1. Return an array of `1`'s and `0`'s, where `1` indicates a row where the value in column `B` equals `A3` (the `--` converts the array into `1`'s and `0`'s - otherwise it contains `TRUE`/`FALSE`)
2. Multiply that array by another array of `1`'s and `0`'s, this time with a `1` indicating a row where column `M` contains the number `1`
3. Finally, multiply that array by all of column `K`. This results in an array of a bunch of `0`'s and then one (or more, depending on your setup) values that represent the value in column `K` where your conditions are met.

**EDIT:** As this deals with text, the `INDEX` formula provided by @barryhoudini (which varies from your original just a bit) will do the trick.

Comment: Ha, just as I wanted to edit my original post with what I have now: `=INDEX('TLN Data'!$B$1:$Z$15000; MATCH(1;(A3='TLN Data'!$B$1:$B$15000)*(1='TLN Data'!$M$1:$M$15000);0); 10)` and this forces me to use that dreadful shift+control+enter combo :P

Comment: @t.thielemans Ha, good old arrays. There is another way to go about it that doesn't involve arrays - I'll update :)

Comment: I found the same too but a slightly bit different and it gave me #VALUE!, yours gives me 0 :s

Comment: Just seems to give me 0 as response :s

Comment: @t.thielemans Hmm, seems to be working on a sample set I've got. Is there any way you could post a sample of your data?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18413/discussion-between-rocketdonkey-and-t-thielemans)